# I am not able to load ng-grid in my application

Tags: angularjs

In page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Welcome to Husys</title>
<link href="~/CSS/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/CustomDirectives/ui-grid.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/appConfig.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Services/HomeService.js"></script>
```

In appConfig.JS

```
var app = angular.module("ApHusys", ['ui.grid']);

    app.run(function ($rootScope){
        $rootScope.MainName = "GlobalName";
    })
```

Am unable to load the grid module in my application, getting an error Module Error

Comment: are you using ng-grid or ui-grid? Are you sure the module name is correct. IF you have a plnkr url , share it, i will take a look

Comment: I used ui-grid and it is mvc application yes the module name is correct     angular.module('ui.grid').controller('uiGridController', ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', 'gridUtil', '$q', 'uiGridConstants',
                    '$templateCache', 'gridClassFactory', '$timeout', '$parse', '$compile',

Comment: Can you update the question with the error text you get in the developer console.

Comment: Bellow are the error Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/modulerr?p0=ApHusys&p1=Error%3…0c%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost_aphusys%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A170)

Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod]  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/nomod?p0=ui.grid

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/1tdcqDcgIS1ggwtPJivQ?p=preview check this plnkr , the module should load successfully. Are you sure the ui.grid.js is not getting a 404. Check the network tab on the dev console and make sure that file is downloaded.

Comment: May be problem in js file i have downloaded ui-grid from cdn it is working now

Comment: i have put my plnkr cdn answer below. Please accept if it helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/release/3.0.0-rc.20/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

[plnkr.co/edit/1tdcqDcgIS1ggwtPJivQ?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/1tdcqDcgIS1ggwtPJivQ?p=preview) check this plnkr , the module should load successfully. Are you sure the ui.grid.js is not getting a 404. Check the network tab on the dev console and make sure that file is downloaded. –

Comment: after correcting the ui-grid link, ng-grid is not working.